# CALL executing transaction control statements

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

What does this paragraph mean about call In postrgesql ?
[source:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-call.html)

> If CALL is executed in a transaction block, then the called procedure
> cannot execute transaction control statements. Transaction control
> statements are only allowed if CALL is executed in its own
> transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the `CALL` statement cannot be part of an explicitly started transaction if you want to use `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` inside the procedure.

This will fail:

```
BEGIN;
CALL myproc();
COMMIT;
```

But called without `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, so that the `CALL` statement runs in its own transaction, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  Could we start another transaction in stored procedure like tsql?

Comment: That happens automatically when you `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. If you want to start the next transaction with the same (non-standard) characteristics (read-only, different isolation level) as the previous one, use `COMMIT AND CHAIN`.